# Designing a trident spout and persisting transaction Ids

Tags: apache-storm

I have been designing a real-engine using storm. I use trident topology to basically aggregate some activities that happen on our website and persist it to cassandra. I was following this article '[Trident State](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-state)' to understand how to persist the values in cassandra. I have tried to define a transactional spout(not sure whether it's actually transactional) by storing the txnId and count in cassandra. My source of input is a RabbitMq queue.

We are updating the count in hourly buckets, ie. all the activities that happened in a hour will be summed up and stored as a single entry in cassandra. The problem i am facing is that as long the topology is running the counts are updated properly. Once i restart the topology, last hourly bucket gets cleared with new count. I am not sure this is because the txnid starts from 1 again. How to get around with this problem.

Cassandra entries before storm restart

```
Key                |   ts                     |  txnId   |  count
viewers:country:US | 2013-11-26 08:00:00-0500 |  1       |     6
viewers:country:US | 2013-11-26 09:00:00-0500 |  2       |     3
viewers:country:US | 2013-11-26 10:00:00-0500 |  3       |     11
```

After storm restart

```
viewers:country:US | 2013-11-26 08:00:00-0500 |  1       |     6
viewers:country:US | 2013-11-26 09:00:00-0500 |  2       |     3
viewers:country:US | 2013-11-26 10:00:00-0500 |  1       |     2
```

In fact for the third entry i am expecting it to become 11 + 2 since it both has same time bucket 2013-11-26. Also txnId is reset to 1. How should i change the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was basically running the topology from with Eclipse IDE as a local cluster. Since zookeeper gets initialized every time I run the program within Eclispe, transaction ids were always starting from 1. When i deploy it on to a cluster of machines, it works fine.